# Modified 'Violent Python' port scanner - prints but doesn't run

Tags: python, security, port

I've been on and off with Python for a while (more off than on), but have started back with 'Violent Python'.  I want to modify the vuln scanner to read from a list of ports, rather than just use a hard-coded list (more for my own understanding than practicality at this point).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Use banner list
# Scan popular ports on a range of hosts

import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv)==3:
   filename = sys.argv[1]
   print "[+] Reading Vulnerabilities From: "+filename
   filename2 = sys.argv[2]
   print "[+] Reading Ports From: "+filename2

def retBanner(ip, port):
   try:
      socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
      s = socket.socket()
      s.connect((ip, port))
      banner = s.recv(1024)
      return banner
   except:
      return

def checkVulns(banner):
   f = open(filename,'r')
   for line in f.readlines():
      if line.strip('\n') in banner:
         print "[+] Server is vulnerable: "+banner.strip('\n')
def main():
   f2 = open(filename2,'r')
   for x in range(1,254):
      ip = '192.168.140.' + str(x)
      for port in f2.readlines():
         banner = retBanner(ip, port)
         if banner:
            print "[+] "+ip+": "+banner
            checkVulns(banner)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

This prints, but nothing happens:

```
root@kali:~/programming/python# ./vuln-scanner-3.py vuln_banners.txt portlist.txt
[+] Reading Vulnerabilities From: vuln_banners.txt
[+] Reading Ports From: portlist.txt
```

In a separate screen session, I'm running tcpdump, with no results (the interface is correct)

```
root@kali:~/programming/python# tcpdump -s0 -vvnn -i eth0 net 192.168.140.0 mask 255.255.255.0 and not 192.168.140.1 and port 22
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

Any thoughts as to why this isn't running properly?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suspect your `tcpdump` expression unless you only care about port 22

Comment: @D.Shawley     ssh is in my port list, as well as the "vulnerable services" (i.e. OpenSSH), so I should at least see that traffic.    `root@kali:~/programming/python# tcpdump -s0 -vvnn -i eth0 net 192.168.140.0 mask 255.255.255.0 and not 192.168.140.1
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
`       Here is a run WITHOUT port 22

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
s.connect((ip, port))
```

see what you provides to it:

```
for port in f2.readlines():
```

You treat port as string! Convert it to int before use:

```
s.connect((ip, int(port)))
```

In addition, tow suggestions for your code:

1. move the "if len(sys.argv)==3:" block into the "if **name** == '**main**':" block.
2. When debug, you might need to disable these try...except to see the error details.

Comment: When I get enough rep to vote you up, I assure you that I will.  Thank you for the wonderful advice and additional pointers.  Aside from custom security tools, I hope to become better with Scapy and Volatility modules.  First, however, I need to learn the basics.  Clearly, I still have a ways to go.  With my own hard work, and concise, helpful tips like those that you provided, I am certain that I will be well on my way.  Thank you again, and regards!

Comment: @Mrdrjnkee Good luck! Security issues are quite hard but also attractive. If you want to be an expert, try to understand the computer on a lower level, like assemble language.